# Cypress - Waiting for an element which has same attributes with other elements already existed

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress

This problem that I'm facing is common for me and I want to learn for about best practices.

My problem is:

I have to wait a text which has an attribute of ".title" class and the text involves the statement of: "Hello". Before triggering this element to come to surface, we have an element already have attributes of ".title" which have a text of "StatementX" as well (At the end of the process, I have 2 ".title" class items on screen).

When I tried to wait for the element "Hello", I write:

```
`cy.get('.title').contains('Hello').should('be.visible')
`
```

Since "StatementX" is already on the screen, Cypress finds ".title" class and does not check "contains" part. What is the best practice to handle such cases?

Thank you so much

Comment: Does the element have anything unique that you could use instead of this `title` class? Do you have access to the HTML? You could add a `data-testid` to the element if so

Comment: Hello, firstly thank you for your precious comment. It is a good idea to add data-testid; however, our company has its own fast development culture. Frontend engineers have no time to put test-ids to old elements. Only difference is the text as I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move the class `.title` into command `.contains()` it will focus solely on the element you wish to test, i.e two criteria will be tested in one command call and it will find the specific element.

```js
cy.contains('.title', 'Hello').should('be.visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any difference at all in those elements you will have a return of an array of elements.

In that part .eq(NUMBER OF THE ARRAY) you can validate the option that you want.

Also you can use XPATH for those cases. Not recommended since it's volatile but since is old stuff that is not changed it should have an higher change of stability.